# Is there a way to communicate with my Redux store from a global Vanilla JS function while using my action creators?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am iteratively rebuilding a legacy system to use React / Redux. It's been working great for the most part! The big problem facing me right now is that the old system had a lot of nested iframes that would use top.functionName() to communicate with the rest of the application. Since I can't rebuild everything at once, I need to write some sort of interface to communicate with my Redux store via top.functionName().

I know I can use $r.store.dispatch to send an action straight to the reducers, but I'd really like to use my action creators directly if possible. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: All that action creators do is return an object that you pass to `dispatch`. So no matter if you're inside React or inside a different part of your app you're always calling `store.dispatch`

Comment: I want to get the benefits of being able to have any additional logic in one spot. Since my functions in, say `actions.js`, are not defined at the global scope, how might I be able to perform something like a thunk? Is there any way to expose that to $r.store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an object with the actions wrapped with `dispatch`, and set the object as a property on `window`:

1. Import all your actions as one object, or combine them all to an object using spread or [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

   ```
   //import * as actionCreators1 from actionCreators1
   //import * as actionCreators2 from actionCreators2
   //import * as actionCreators3 from actionCreators3

   const actionCreators = { ...actionCreators1, ...actionCreators2, ...actionCreators3, etc... };
   ```

   The actions' object should be something like this

   ```
   const actionCreators = {
       actionA: (payload) => ({ type: 'actionA', payload }),
       actionB: (payload) => ({ type: 'actionB', payload }),
       // etc...
   };
   ```
2. Wrap the actions with dispatch using [`bindActionCreators`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html), and assign them to a property on `window`:

   ```
   const demoStore = createStore(reducer);

   window.reduxActions = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, demoStore.dispatch);
   ```
3. Call your actions from the iframes using:

   ```
   top.reduxActions.actionA(15);
   ```